# How to animate one end of react-native-skia Path or Line

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

The code below does not generate any errors. BUT, during the return, which occurs during a pan gesture, the Circle moves as it should, but the the Path end and Line end do not move. I want either the Path or the Line end to move with the Circle (once it works, i'll remove the +-20 in the args).

The problem seems to be that the Path and Line need to access the quantities `skiaX` and `skiaY` (each of these is a 'SkiaMutableValue' which are updated via `useSharedValueEffect`), not just the 'numbers' `skiaX.current` and `skiaY.current`, or `currentX.value` and `currentY.value` (which for some Skia reason are not updated when accessed during the return).

However, the Line and Path will only accept points of 'number' type (`skiaX.current` and `skiaY.current`, or `currentX.value` and `currentY.value`).

Notice that the Circle DOES access `skiaX` and `skiaY`. Any ideas on how to allow the Line or Path to somehow also access the quantites `skiaX` and `skiaY` (not just `skiaX.current` and `skiaY.current`, or `currentX.value` and `currentY.value`)? Thanks for reading!

```
import {Canvas,
        Circle,
        Line,
        vec,
        Path,
        Rect,
        Skia,
        useSharedValueEffect,
        useValue,
    } from '@shopify/react-native-skia';
import React from 'react';
import {Dimensions, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import {
        Gesture,
        GestureDetector,
        GestureHandlerRootView,
    } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, {
        useAnimatedStyle,
        useSharedValue,
        withSpring,
    } from 'react-native-reanimated';
  
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
  
const App = () => {
    const strokeWidth = 5;
    const circleRadius = 15;

    const centerX = width / 2;
    const centerY = height / 2;
  
    const initialX = useSharedValue(centerX);
    const initialY = useSharedValue(centerY);
    const currentX = useSharedValue(centerX);
    const currentY = useSharedValue(centerY);

    const skiaX = useValue(centerX);
    const skiaY = useValue(centerY);  

    const gesture = Gesture.Pan()

      .onUpdate(({translationX, translationY}) => {
        currentX.value = translationX + initialX.value;
        currentY.value = translationY + initialY.value;        
      })

      .onEnd(() => {
        currentX.value = withSpring(initialX.value);
        currentY.value = withSpring(initialY.value);
        });
  
    useSharedValueEffect(
      () => {
        skiaX.current = currentX.value;
        skiaY.current = currentY.value;
      },
      currentX,
      currentY,
    );
  
    return (
      <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.container}>
        <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Canvas style={styles.canvas}>
              <Rect x={0} y={0} width={width} height={height} color="black" />
              
              <Path
                path={`M ${currentX.value - 20} ${currentY.value + 20} L ${width/2} ${height/2}`}
                style="stroke"
                strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
                strokeCap="round"
                color={'orange'}
              />
              
              <Line
                p1={vec(skiaX.current + 20, skiaY.current + 20)}
                p2={vec(width/2, height/2)}
                color="white"
                style="stroke"
                strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
              />

              <Circle
                cx={skiaX}
                cy={skiaY}
                r={circleRadius}
                color="green"
                style="fill"
              />
              
            </Canvas>
          </View>
        </GestureDetector>
      </GestureHandlerRootView>
    );
};
  
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
    },
    canvas: {
      flex: 1,
    },
    cursor: {
      backgroundColor: 'green',
    },
  });
  
  export default App;
```

For example, if I replace the line

`path={`M ${skiaX.current - 20} ${skiaY.current + 20} L ${width/2} ${height/2}`}`

with

`path={`M ${skiaX - 20} ${skiaY + 20} L ${width/2} ${height/2}`}`

this error is generated:  "Error is: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'SkiaMutableValue' and 'number'."